# Modify Output on onClick() Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to center the image when the user opens the image in a chrome-less window and not center the chrome-less window itself.

The following is what I have:

```
<img src="DSC01646_tn.jpg" alt="img" onclick="window.open('/share/Company Halloween 2018/DSC01646.jpg', 'newwindow', 'DSC01646.jpg', 'width=auto, height=auto')"/>
```

I would like to add the following styling css class "***mod***" to modify the output of the image.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: @Peter B, Barmer: I am not asking to center the chromeless window but to center the image that is in the window.

Comment: For centering the window, see the duplicate. And for this part: `add the following styling css class "mod" to modify the output of the image` -> you **can't** style an image this way, you need HTML (which contains e.g. an `<img>` tag) to do so. If needed, edit the question so it can be considered for re-opening.

Comment: @PeterB: Thank you. Again, not asking to center the window. Regarding the second part of your response, then their is not a way to modify the output on how the image will be displayed correct?

Comment: Not with just an image. There needs to be a DOM document, and with just an image there is no DOM document.